# Callback function from Flask to React.js

Tags: reactjs, flask

I'm New to Web Development and React.js. I'm trying to develop a Website With React Front End and Flask backend. There's a long-running Task (about 30 mins) in my back end (Job starts from the front end with some inputs). Is there a way to set up a callback function to React from Flask when the job is Finished Running?

Comment: You should use WebSocket to notify the client when the task has been completed in the backend

Comment: Thanks, @SirwanAfifi for your Answer. Are there any other viable, simple options apart from Socket? (Having some issues with implementing Sockets)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of these tasks going on, it might be worth setting up WebSockets.
Otherwise it is also viable, and probably easier to implement when getting started, to use a standard HTTP request and only answer it after the backend task is completed.

To make the logic more easily understandable, some pseudo code:

Backend:

```
@app.route('/job/<data>')
def backend_job(data):
  run_long_backend_job(data)
  return "All done!"
```

Frontend:

```
fetch('https://myapi.dev/job/test')
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Request completed!');
    // Your callback code goes here
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    // This is executed when the request fails
  });
```

HTTP requests allow you to send data to a server, have it execute some code and then receive an answer in return. I recommend looking up some HTTP request tutorials if you haven't used them before, they are a great tool!

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. But the issue is, the long-running Task Takes about 30 - 45 minutes to complete. The task has a lot to do with data processing and once the result is given to the front end, The Front end doesn't need to call the backend unless the user starts another long-running task. (I implemented a caching Mechanism If the user request the same task, it'll only return the result)

Comment: You can have your server start processing when it receives the request and then respond after it has finished the 30-45 minute task. The callback will then be executed in the frontend only after it receives the response.

Comment: Thank You @Jotha. I thought that would not be a good idea to wait for a response for 30 minutes. What I currently do is, After the Submission, I check the Task Status every 3 Seconds Until the Job is complete. Is Waiting for a response for 30 minutes is better than Having the Current Setup in an Architectural Perspective?

Comment: I would recommend staying with your current model. It allows the task to be completed even if the users network connection drops for a short time, and it is also more flexible because it allows you to do things like return different status messages (e.g. 'Waiting', 'Processing (x%)' etc.).